# Make the product of two most maximum value in array(Java)

Tags: java, arrays, oop

Suppose we have a double array like so:

```
double [] array=new double[5]
```

The user enters values which are stored in the array. My task is to determine the product of the two largest values in the array.

How do I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean the product of the maximum and the second maximum value of the array?

Comment: yes dear rafi kamal

Comment: Do you want the product of the two highest values or the highest product with two values out of your array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
static Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    double[] array = new double[5];
    System.out.println("enter number");

    //for loop to fill array 
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        array[i] = read.nextDouble();
    }

    double max1 = 0;

    //for loop to find first max value 
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] > max1) {
            max1 = array[i];
        }
    }
    double max2 = 0;

    //for loop to find second max value 
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] > max2 && array[i] != max1) {
            max2 = array[i];
        }
    }

    System.out.println("the product of two most maximum value is " + (max1 * max2));     // the product of two max value
    // end main
}
```

Comment: @ruba ahmad your program will return 100.0 two time try to use `double[] array = {100, 6, 3, 99, 8};` and you will see :)

Comment: @Khezar Bangash try to use this values 100, 5, 6, 9, 3 and check what will return this program !

Comment: you already have a problem in your loop, you can check the `variable i is already defined in method main(String[])` :)

Comment: i think your `}  // end main` should be before the `double max2 = 0;` :)

Comment: @MrLY you can use the same variable in different block :)

Comment: yes i know, i already fix your problem good luck now your program work :)

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;

class Test {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        double array[] = {2, 98, 1, 5, 3, 6};

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < array.length; j++) {
                if (array[j] > array[i]) {
                    double temp = array[i];
                    array[i] = array[j];
                    array[j] = temp;
                }
            }
        }

        double product = array[0] * array[1];
        System.out.println(product);
    }
}
```

**P.S:**

I have edited my previous answer as i came to know that the `Arrays.sort()` method won't work for type double it works for types:- `int`, `byte`, `short`, `char` or `object[]` arrays only.

Comment: Sort the array in descending order and multiply 0th and 1st index elements. It is more easier..

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class HelloWorld{

    public static void main(String []args){
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        double[] array = new double[5];
        for(int i = 0; i<5; i++)
        {
            array[i] = scan.nextDouble();
        }
        double max = array[0];
        for(int i= 1; i<5; i++)
        {
            if(array[i] > max)
            {
                max = array[i];
            }
        }
        double prev = array[0];
        for(int i= 1; i<5; i++)
        {
            if(array[i] > prev && array[i] < max)
            {
                prev = array[i];
            }
        }
        System.out.println(max*prev);
    }
}
```